# In Rust, when assertion fails hop into debugger

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust

A simple library that has been very convenient, indispensable even, in C# is

```
namespace SharedLibraries.Verification { public static class Verify {

    // conditions that must be satisfied in order to use a module go here
    public static void Require(bool B) {
        if (B) return;
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
    }

    // things that should be provably true if the Require(s) of a module are met
    public static void Assert(bool B) {
        if (B) return;
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
    }

    public static void AssertFail() {
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
    }

}}

namespace SharedLibraries.VerificationOff { public static class Verify {

    [System.Diagnostics.Conditional("DoNotEverTurnThisOn")]
    public static void Require(bool B) {}

    [System.Diagnostics.Conditional("DoNotEverTurnThisOn")]
    public static void Assert(bool B) {}

    [System.Diagnostics.Conditional("DoNotEverTurnThisOn")]
    public static void AssertFail() {}
}}
```

If a requirement or assertion fails, it pops me into the debugger.  When I want to turn it off, I just change the include command from Verification to VerificationOff.  It won't even compute "B" when it is turned off so there is no overhead.

I have been trying all kinds of different things to try to make a Rust/VSCode library to do the same thing.  Here is what I have so far:

```
pub mod on {
    pub fn require<Predicate: FnOnce() -> bool>(check : Predicate) {
        if cfg!(debug_assertions) {
            if !check() {
                unsafe {
                    println!("before debug break");
                    winapi::um::debugapi::DebugBreak();
                    println!("after debug break");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    pub fn assert<Predicate: FnOnce() -> bool>(check : Predicate) {
        if cfg!(debug_assertions) {
            if !check() {
                unsafe {
                    winapi::um::debugapi::DebugBreak();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

pub mod off {
    pub fn require<Predicate: FnOnce() -> bool>(_check : Predicate) {}
    pub fn assert <Predicate: FnOnce() -> bool>(_check : Predicate) {}
}
```

This works at least when the above code is in the same crate as the program that is executed.  But when it is included from a standalone crate using "extern crate verifier" (or whatever name) then whenever an assertion fails the program just crashes and the debugger closes down.  And it crashes exactly on the winapi call.  The debugger vscode is using is cppvsdbg for windows.

I'm looking for help to make this work.  Maybe converting to macros or using a different command to get the debuggers attention.  I'm very fresh with rust so please be explicit.

Comment: You could just put a break point inside the method?

Comment: I know next to nothing about vscode, but I still would be very surprised if a breakpoint set in one workspace/crate would somehow be respected by an import command in another workspace/crate.

Comment: @PeterHall, that requires you to know which assert will crash in advance. Ideally the debugger would activate on panic by default; that's almost certainly what the user wants when they run a crashy program in a debugger.